# Delete a node lxml python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml, nodes, removechild

I have found a lot of examples to `remove element node` in an XML file. BUt here is an example for which I didnt find any solution either on stackoverflow or google.
For example:

```
<slide>
    America
    <a> 2 </a>
    <b> 3 </b>
    <c> 4 </c>
</slide>

<slide>
    Germany
    <a> 5 </a>
    <b> 6 </b>
    <c> 7 </c>
</slide>
```

I would use `remove` function to delete an element node, since I am using lxml. But now I have to delete "America" and "Germany" which are not actually element nodes but text.

is there a way to remove this like any function??

I am currently using python lxml library.

Output should look like :

```
 <slide>
     <a> 2 </a>
     <b> 3 </b>
     <c> 4 </c>
 </slide>

 <slide>
     <a> 5 </a>
     <b> 6 </b>
     <c> 7 </c>
 </slide>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`text`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#text) property. For example:

```
html = '''...
<slide>
    America
    <a> 2 </a>
    <b> 3 </b>
    <c> 4 </c>
</slide>

<slide>
    Germany
    <a> 5 </a>
    <b> 6 </b>
    <c> 7 </c>
</slide>
....'''

import lxml.html
root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
for slide in root.xpath('.//slide'):
    slide.text = ''
```

Comment: @SangameshHs: The shortcut to saying the same thing is the Accept button :P

Comment: lol..well i cannnot accpet the answer until next 6 minutes :P :)